# Plone Internal Link -content type

Tags: plone

Plone has out of the box content type for externel links.

Does there exist such content type, way or add-on for internal links?

Real links, not aliases.

Comment: And what would the internal link be defined as? A path within the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wrote vs.alias

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/vs.alias

which refers to other internal objects through a reference field.

Comment: I thought someone had to do this before :)

Answer (score 1):

Smart Link? http://plone.org/products/redturtle.smartlink